# How to run a command when ssh connection closes

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I know that I can run additional scripts on login if I place them in /etc/ssh/sshrc is there a pendant for logout/ disconnect?

running openssh

Answer (score 2):

I know of no such option to ssh.  The shell you are running may have the ability to do this though.  An example would be ~/.bash_logout when you're using the bash shell.